# How to serialize two attributes into one json property using Newtonsoft in C#?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

In the ScanInfo class there are two version of scan result. But only one of these two attributes will be empty, the other attribute will have value. In this case, I only want to serialize the non-empty attribute and the output json property name is "scanResult". The current code will report property name conflict when I try to serialize. How can I fix this?

```
public class ScanInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("scanResult", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ScanResult oldVersion;

    [JsonProperty("scanResult", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ScanResultNew newVersion;

}

public class ScanResult 
{
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime EndTime;
    public IDictionary<string, long> statistic;
}
public class ScanResultNew 
{
    public DateTime StartTime;
    public DateTime EndTime;
    public Statistic statistic;
    public string status;
}
```

Json output:

```
{
    "scanResult":...
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTH28.jpg)

My aim is that only one of them should be serialized and both should be referred by property name "scanResult".

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot? On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content in posts, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.  For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*.

Comment: What do you mean by when you say an "attribute" is "empty"?  Do these two properties actually have different return types?  Could you [edit] your question to share a [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks! I have modified the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution could be to add the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to the two current `ScanResult` fields, and add a new public property that serializes to "scanResult". This new property could do the "filtering" of which of the results to serialize.

Here's an example:

```
public class ScanInfo
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ScanResult oldVersion;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ScanResult newVersion;

    [JsonProperty("scanResult", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ScanResult ActualScanResult
    {
        get
        {
            if(newVersion != null) 
            {
                return newVersion;
            }
            else
            {
                return oldVersion;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a quick gif that shows that it works:

[image: Screen recording while debugging the code, to show that the solution works.]

Comment: Thanks Lars! Nice solution. But my situation is these two attributes are based on two different classes (ScanResult & ScanResultNew). Two class definitions are different.

Comment: Using `Object` to accept two different type instance also works! Thanks very much!

Comment: @rutonggaoya Ah I missed that part of your question, sorry.  Yes, setting the type of the new property to `object` will solve it, but I would reccommend giving both classes an interface (e.g. `IScanResult`) and setting the property to return an instance of that interface. If my answer helped solve your issue, please mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks! Using interface is reasonable. But the fields of the two classes are quite different. They have some of the same fields and they have their own unique fields. Is it possible to use a single interface `IScanResult` to accept it?

Comment: @rutonggaoya You can add the fields that are the same to the interface. Just keep in mind that you have to cast your ActualScanResult onto the respective classes if you want to access fields that are unique to that class.

Comment: @Sigmarod Yes, it works. Thx~